# How can I login multiple accounts using telethon...?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I am trying to build a python script which requires login with multiple telegram accounts. I don't want to run a separate script for each account.I am using TELETHON. I know that there is something like `create_new_connection` in telethon, but I don't know how it can help me. Is there a way by which I can use just one python script and login using several accounts..?
(If possible please include the code snippet to use in your answer)

Comment: > *I know that there is something like `create_new_connection` in telethon*. There isn't (it used to be a thing but was removed). In any case it wouldn't do what you want.

Answer (score 14):

When you create a client, the first parameter you pass is the session file name. Different sessions can have different clients logged in, so it's enough to create multiple clients each with a different session file name for them to use different accounts:

```
user1 = TelegramClient('user1', api_id, api_hash)
user2 = TelegramClient('user2', api_id, api_hash)
```

Of course, you could also use a list to trivially support an arbitrary number of clients. What you do with these clients is up to you, although you will generally just take advantage of [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) as explained in the [Python documentation - Running Tasks Concurrently](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently):

```py
import asyncio

async def work(client):
    async with client:
        me = await client.get_me()
        print('Working with', me.first_name)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        work(TelegramClient('user1', api_id, api_hash)),
        work(TelegramClient('user2', api_id, api_hash)),
    )

asyncio.run(main())
```

You could, of course, run separate code for each, use conditionals, etc. It depends a lot on your needs, and what these are will influence your design too.

Comment: Yeah..! Thanks a lot buddy. I tried the above code, it's working perfectly fine.But I am having one small problem with events. How do I handle events using asyncio.gather..?

Comment: Just like you can use client methods on each client, you can use them in decorators or to call add event handler. The documentation lists what methods are available.

Comment: @Lonami could you please give a hint, what is the preferrable way to run multiple "polling" with Telethon? Is it fine to running multiple `create_task` with `clientX.start() clientX.run_until_disconnected()`?

Comment: @Lonami Do you also know how to add or remove clients at runtime?

Comment: @Alp you will need to keep a list of spawned tasks so that they can all run at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @Lonami. Care to show an example of how it could look like?

Comment: `create_task` is how you spawn new tasks, storing them somewhere (like `append`ing to a list) is just a good idea so you can cancel or refer to them later (they will run even if you don't store them, but then you lose some control).

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple clients

```
user1 = TelegramClient(...)
user2 = TelegramClient(...)
```

Comment: While this is the right way to go, the answer is a bit vague: it doesn't explain why this works, the fact that different session files are needed and why, and also does not explain how to run them both at the same time.