# How to Log In Multiple Telegram Accounts and Send Messages to a Group

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I have some Telegram accounts and a group. I want my accounts to send messages like `/summon_boss` to the group so I can summon the boss and then kill it for a reward. But I don't know how to get my account to send messages to that group using python, so I don't have to open my accounts one by one because it's tiring.

I don't know which code should I use to log in my accounts. Either this...

```
clients = [
  TelegramClient('session1', phone_number_1, api_id, api_hash),
  TelegramClient('session2', phone_number_2, api_id, api_hash),
  TelegramClient('session3', phone_number_3, api_id, api_hash),
]
```

...or this.

```
client1 = TelegramClient('session1', phone_number_1, api_id, api_hash) 
client2 = TelegramClient('session2', phone_number_2, api_id, api_hash)
client3 = TelegramClient('session3', phone_number_3, api_id, api_hash)
```

All I know is that we can use the same `api_id` and `api_hash` for multiple accounts. I don't know how to log in multiple accounts in one session, then make those accounts send the same message in the same group too. I hope you understand what I'm asking. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62559942/.