# How to run multiple sessions using telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I need to run multiple Telegram accounts (that all use the same message handler) using telethon.
Exactly, I need to:

- run a function (one time per account)
- run the handler (forever)

This is the code now, I just need to run it with more than one client. I have a list of accounts, and I must use that.

```
async def main(client):
    me = await client.get_me()
    print("Working with", me.first_name)
    await client.send_message("@example", "example")

client = TelegramClient(f'telegram_session', account["API_ID"], account["API_HASH"])
client.add_event_handler(handler, events.NewMessage())

with client:
    client.start()
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main(client))
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this.

```
def get_or_create_eventloop():
    try:
        return asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError as ex:
        if "There is no current event loop in thread" in str(ex):
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            return asyncio.get_event_loop()

def run(account): 
    loop = get_or_create_eventloop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(work(account))
    loop.run_until_complete(future)

accounts= [dict(session = 'user1', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)]
for account in accounts:
    threading.Thread(target = run, args = [account ]).start()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems like a possible path to follow. I will try it and post here what happens.

Comment: I tried it, got this error:
`ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected`

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to use the `connect` or `start` method. @GitJorgo

Comment: In the `work()` function, first create an object from the `TelegramClient` and then turn it on with the `connect`, and then use methods such as `get_me()`

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve. I had to create another script to login, to avoid getting all the codes concurrently. Then, awaiting client.connect() in the work function worked good.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick look at the library you are using, it is based on asynio. I think you should to do something like this

```
  asyncio.wait([one_task(), two_task()])
```

P.S i found answer  here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62558913/how-can-i-login-multiple-accounts-using-telethon)